# Greater than, less than confusion

Tags: discussion

Why do Q & A require **&lt;** and **&gt;** to produce greater than less than whereas comments require literal **<** and **>** ? It seems inconsistent and inevitably I end up making an edit to fix it in one place or another.

I hesitated to try them in the title because I don't want to know.

Is it simply the browser behaviour of input vs textarea and can it be tweaked or something like that?

Comment: Why would you use < or > outside of a code element?

Comment: The limitations should at least be documented in the FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions and Answers allows actual HTML in them, while comments only allow markdown I believe.

AKA, In an **Question or Answer I can do this**

Source Code:

```
AKA, In an <strong>Question or Answer I can do this</strong>
```

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea that you could put HTML in questions and/or answers. Thanks!